# What is wrong with the question "Formalizations of unsolved problems"?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

There are comments suggesting that the question [Formalization of unsolved problems](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/formalizations-of-unsolved-problems) should be closed because it doesn't contain the big-list tag.  I don't understand this.  **Am I missing something?**

First, I think it is a legitimate question.  I think there are only two small issues:

- It could be more clear that it is talking about unsolved problems in mathematics (like the RH) compared to unsolved problems in proof assistants (like FLT).
- It is a bit similar to [Libraries of formally stated theorems with proofs verified by humans](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/683) and maybe that makes it a duplicate.  (I don't think it is, but maybe that other question nonetheless answers this one.)

I also don't see why it is "way too open ended" or needs a big-list tag.  I think if such a library exists (which it probably doesn't) there would only be one or two such examples.  I don't think every question of the form "is there a proof assistant which does X?" or "is there a library of X?" needs a big-list tag.

But maybe I'm not looking at this the right way.

Comment: Also, if the question is still up after I end work today and not closed or already answered, I'll give my best shot at an answer.

Comment: Ok, I was conflating the two issues.  Sorry for that.  But I'm still not sure why it was too open?  Or even how it could be narrowed down in a way that doesn't change its meaning entirely. I would concede that if the OP provided more motivation for why they want a list, that might help (and that is good advice for all OPs).

Comment: (By "list" I meant "library".)

Comment: I don't see any problem with the linked question. It doesn't need a `big-list` tag and I don't see what the "focus" problem is: as asked it has a simple yes/no answer, and if the answer is "yes", a link to such a project can be given. Andrej has already given such an answer.

Comment: Just to add some context as the author of that question originally, my intent was not to get a list of libraries. My intent was to establish whether there is *any* such library. I also don't think the question is particularly open ended, other than the fact that if there are multiple such libraries, then any of them would suffice as an answer.